# Frontend css cache issue

Tags: cache, frontend, css

Having an issue with multisite where I edit css for each store to set image widths and height, for some reason the css isn't updating on certain sites. One of them took effect after clearing css/js cache in Cache Management, however the others are not. I have manually purged var/cache folder and cannot figure out why these other css files are not being updated on the frontend. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have CSS/JSS merge turned on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looked at the block in the database, turns out there was styling in the block itself that wasn't showing up on the wysiwyg editor that was conflicting. So just as a note for anyone who wants to try and put `<style>` tags directly in their block, I strongly advise against that as it has very odd behavior such as not showing up in wysiwyg. If you do have this problem, simply copy paste the content of your block, make note of your block specific settings such as URL key and store views, and create a new block after deleting the old one. This fixed the issue in my case, as well as clearing browser cache and server cache, refreshing any server side cache, clearing CSS/JS cache in admin, and cleaning the contents of var/cache manually.

Answer (score 2):

May be it is due to full page caching or any other caching mechanism or cdn, if you are using any of them.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, we are using this on our development server, and have full page cache, compiler, and normal caches disabled. Additionally, this is a multi-site deployment, and the changes take effect on other sites but some just don't update. We also don't use cloudflare on this site until we have it production ready. The only factor I can determine is local browser cache, but I have already cleared all my cache and tried it in Firefox/Chrome with the same results. In any event, I gave it time to settle overnight and let any unknown cache expire, and it works fine now.